# PDFBox: No glyph for U+0050 in extracted font

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

I'm trying to create new page in document and write some text to it, while using the font contained in the file.

The font is extracted from the resources:

```
PDPage page = document.getPage(0);
PDResources res = page.getResources();

List<PDFont> fonts = new ArrayList<>();

for (COSName fontName : res.getFontNames()) {
     PDFont font = res.getFont(fontName);
     System.out.println(font);
     fonts.add(font);
}
```

And later used to write some text:

```
stream.beginText();
stream.setFont(fonts.get(0), 12);
stream.setTextMatrix(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(20, 50));
stream.showText("Protokol");
stream.endText();
```

The `showText` method always fails with error

> No glyph for U+0050 (P) in font QZHBRL+ArialMT

But the glyph is there, as verified by FontForge:
[image]

Also the method `hasGlyph` returns true.

The complete project including the PDF is available at [github repository showing the issue](https://github.com/sutr90/pdfbox-font-problem)

Comment: your test code was very useful in helping to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in issue [PDFBOX-5103](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5103). This will be available in PDFBox 2.0.23 and until then, in a [snapshot build](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.23-SNAPSHOT/).

Answer (score 4):

Here you actually ran into an open PDFBox TODO, your `stream.showText` eventually calls `encode` of the underlying CID font for each character and here we have:

```java
public class PDCIDFontType2 extends PDCIDFont
{
    ...
    public byte[] encode(int unicode)
    {
        int cid = -1;
        if (isEmbedded)
        {
            ...
            // otherwise we require an explicit ToUnicode CMap
            if (cid == -1)
            {
                //TODO: invert the ToUnicode CMap?
                // see also PDFBOX-4233
                cid = 0;
            }
        }
        ...
        if (cid == 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format("No glyph for U+%04X (%c) in font %s", unicode, (char) unicode, getName()));
        }

        return encodeGlyphId(cid);
    }
    ...
}
```

*(`org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2`)*

Where PDFBox could not otherwise determine a mapping from Unicode to glyph code (`if (cid == -1)`), the JavaDoc comments indicate another way to determine a glyph code, an inverse lookup of the **ToUnicode** map. If this was implemented, PDFBox could have determined a glyph ID and written your text.

Unfortunately it is not implemented yet.